# TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.interactions.Interaction'>

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord command attempting to integrate Dall-E:

````
import opena9
from Classes import Dalle
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import discord
from discord import Message as DiscordMessage, Color
import logging
from openai import Image
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


@tree.command(name="hallucinate", description="Generate dall-e images using your query.")
@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(send_messages=True)
@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(view_channel=True)
@discord.app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(send_messages=True)
@discord.app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(view_channel=True)
@discord.app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_threads=True)
async def dalle_command(ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction, *, query: str):

    if not isinstance(interaction.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        return

 if not isinstance(interaction.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        return

    user = interaction.user
    logger.info(f"Dall-E command by {user} asked to draw {query[:20]}")

    try:
        # moderate the message
        flagged_str, blocked_str = moderate_message(message=query, user=user)
        await send_moderation_blocked_message(
            guild=interaction.guild,
            user=user,
            blocked_str=blocked_str,
            message=query,
        )
        if len(blocked_str) > 0:
            # message was blocked
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                f"Your prompt has been blocked by moderation.\n{query}",
                ephemeral=True,
            )
            return

        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"<@{user.id}> asked to draw {query[:20]}",
            color=discord.Color.green(),
        )
        embed.add_field(name=user.name, value=query)

        if len(flagged_str) > 0:
            # message was flagged
            embed.color = discord.Color.yellow()
            embed.title = "⚠️ This prompt was flagged by moderation."

        await interaction.response.defer()
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)

        response = await interaction.original_response()

        await send_moderation_flagged_message(
            guild=interaction.guild,
            user=user,
            flagged_str=flagged_str,
            message=query,
            url=response.jump_url,
        )
        if not query:
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                "DALL·E: Invalid query\nPlease enter a query (e.g !dalle dogs on space).")
            return

            # Check if query is too long
        if len(query) > 100:
            await interaction.response.send_message("DALL·E: Invalid query\nQuery is too long! (Max length: 100 chars)")
            return

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"Failed to start chat {str(e)}", ephemeral=True
        )
        return

    message = await interaction.response.send_message("Generating your query (this may take 1 or 2 minutes):"
                                                      " ```" + query + "```")

    try:
        dall_e = await Dalle.DallE(prompt=f"{query}", author=f"{user.id}")
        generated = await dall_e.generate()

        if len(generated) > 0:
            first_image = Image.open(generated[0].path)
            generated_collage = await _create_collage(ctx, query, first_image, generated)

            # Prepare the attachment
            file = discord.File(generated_collage, filename="art.png")
            await interaction.response.send_message(file=file)

            # Delete the message
            await message.delete()
````

Which returns this error when it builds in Heroku:

```
File "/app/src/main.py", line 159, in <module>
async def dalle_command(ctx, interaction: discord.Interaction, *, query: str):
TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.interactions.Interaction'>
```

Line 159 being the line on which the function is defined.

Based on some other posts on this error, it seems that maybe there is a problem with the order I am declaring these parameters, but I'm not sure what it is. How should I be declaring this function?

Comment: The `ctx` parameter doesn't make sense for application commands like this. Get rid of it and refactor `_create_collage` so that it doesn't rely on it

Comment: This did fix the error above, thank you. If I could trouble you further, why is that the case?

Comment: The "ctx" is used for text-based prefix commands only. Most importantly, it stores the message which invoked the command. Slash commands are not invoked from a message at all; it's an entirely separate process (called an interaction).